# Why is Symfony's "dev" firewall handling css|images|js?

Tags: php, symfony, security, assets, firewall

In the [Symfony Security docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall) the `dev` firewall is configured.

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
```

I understand why `_(profiler|wdt)` is included in the `pattern`, but I cannot understand why `css|images|js` is included. I guess the files in these folders typically contain (static) assets that are not served by the Symfony app. And, if these folders were containing application code, I would not want to route them through a firewall that allows all access. Am I missing something?

The docs explain:

> The `dev` firewall is really a fake firewall: it makes sure that you don't accidentally block Symfony's dev tools - which live under URLs like `/_profiler` and `/_wdt`.

No mention of `css|images|js`. The rest of the internet (aka Google) did not come up with a proper explanation.

Comment: It's a fake firewall, the "dev" is a misnomer. It simply says "do not apply security constraints to these paths". Static assets (css, image, js) are typically not under security (they are typically just static files and that's it). You could remove that part of the rule, and the profiler (and the rest of the application) would continue to work. Frankly, I think that part of the rule was simply left there from some time in the past where it could have made sense. In most setups that make sense nowadays, static files would be served by the webserver and skip the application layer entirely.

Comment: Yes, that's the case for local development with nginx, caddy, or apache. But are you sure @yivi that this line is not needed for local development with a PHP server or the Symfony client? I rather have the feeling that it's for this case that this line is present."

Comment: @Alexandre The "symfony" binary, as far as I can see, simply starts a different webserver. It's written on Go, and 99% sure will serve static files directly if they exist, as any sane web server; and never go through the application layer (don't have it installed it now, but feel free to confirm it yourself). The PHP built-in server (`php -S`) will serve existing files directly, never hitting the application layer and the security config.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. IMHO, you should post your comment as an answer!

Comment: OK! @yivi, thanks! This confirms my thoughts. Thanks alot!